# React - array of components - this.prop is always prop of last component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, web-component

I'm currently having some issues with my react props. I have a `Songs` class which contains an array of 10 songs and each of the `song` components has its own `playPause` component with a `number` prop. Accessing `this.props.number` in `playPause` works fine in all functions, except one.

This returns fitting numbers for all components (1-10 except for the one clicked) - Edit: full code for this bit is basically [the same as this](https://codesandbox.io/s/30q3mzjv91?module=%2Fsrc%2FOutsideAlerter.js):

```
handleClickOutside=(event)=> {
        if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
           console.log(this.props.number);
        }
    };
```

Edit: onStateChanged is part of the [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/reference/#event-player-state-changed) - it gets called when the player state changes (play/pause).

This returns only number 10 (the number prop of the last component) - no matter which component calls the function.

```
createEventHandlers()
{
this.player.on('player_state_changed',state => this.onStateChanged(state));}

onStateChanged=(state)=> {
        if (state !== null) {
                if(state.paused){
                    console.log(this.props.number); //returns 10
                }
        }

    };
```

Edit: some more code:

```
componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
    }

setWrapperRef=(node)=> {
        this.wrapperRef = node;
    };

render() {
        return(
            <div ref={this.setWrapperRef}>
            <div className={this.state.playing ? 'overlay visible': "overlay"} onClick={this.togglePlayIcon}>
                <b className="icon" title="Play Song">
                    <i className={this.state.playState}></i>
                </b>
            </div>
            </div>
    );

checkForPlayer()
{
    clearInterval(this.playerCheckInterval);

    if (window.Spotify !== null) {
        this.player = new window.Spotify.Player({
            name: "Top10 Spotify Player",
            getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(PlayPause.readCookie("access_token")); },
            volume: 0.1
        });
        this.createEventHandlers();

        // finally, connect!
        this.player.connect();
    }
}
```

I guess I need to bind `this` somewhere, but I can't figure out where exactly. Any advice?

Comment: I think we need to see a little more code to properly answer this question. Please post as much as you can.

Comment: Though its very hard to comment exactly what went wrong seeing the snippet of your code here, but if you are using a loop to list all the items you need to make sure that each item gets a unique id. This is a suggestion, might help you to debug.